# Randomize LiveData<List<names>

Tags: java, android, random, android-livedata

How can I randomize a `LiveData<list<StudentEntity>>` in a `ViewModel` and display the results in my `RecyclerView`? I was thinking I could do a

```
Collection.shuffle(Arrays.asList(myList))
```

but I don't believe this changes the order of the objects in the LiveDatalist.

MyFragment

```
....
public void RandomizeListOrder() {
    mMainActivityViewModel.setRandomOrder();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

ViewModel

```
private LiveData<List<StudentEntity>> mStudentList

public void setRandomOrder() {
    Collection.shuffle(Arrays.asList(mStudentList));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate livedata using livedata transformations.

```
val transformedLiveData = Transformations.map(
                yourActualLiveData) { //Shuffle logic here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are interested in Kotlin solution you could do it like this:

```
val mStudentList = MutableLiveData<List<StudentEntity>>()

fun setRandomOrder() {
    mStudentList.value?.let { students ->
        mStudentList.value = students.shuffled()
    }
}
```